# Ransack::Search object was provided to search_form_for

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I am trying to add a search form on the home page of a web app to search for schools like this;

```
<%= search_form_for @q, url: schools_path, html: { method: :post, :class => 'course-finder-form' } do |f| %>                
    <%= f.label :school_name_cont %>
    <%= f.text_field :school_name_cont %>
    <%= f.submit %>                                                                        
<% end %><!--//course-finder-form-->
```

and the schools controller looks like this;

```
  def index
    @q = School.search(params[:q])
    @schools = @q.result.order("school_name ASC").page(params[:page]).per(50)    

    respond_to do |format|
     format.html # index.html.erb
     format.json { render json: @schools }
    end
  end
```

And the rendering controller **home controller**

```
def index
  @q = School.search
end
```

But on running the app i get this error;

```
No Ransack::Search object was provided to search_form_for!
```

Any idea how to go about this?

Comment: I cannot see what is causing this however to be getting this error it means `@q` is not being set before the view is rendered.  All I can suggest is you debug or put some trace in both index actions to be 100% sure it is being set.

Answer (score 1):

You are not passing in a search object, but instead a symbol `:q`.  You are also not being consistent about calling the search `search` or `q`.  You can use either but `q` is now the Ransack default.

In your view change:

```
<% search_form_for :q, url: schools_path, html: { method: :post, :class => 'course-finder-form' } do |f| %>
```

to be:

```
<%= search_form_for @q, url: schools_path, html: { method: :post, :class => 'course-finder-form' } do |f| %>
```

And in your controller change:

```
def index
  @search = School.search(params[:q])
  @products = @search.result.order("school_name ASC").page(params[:page]).per(50)
  ...
```

to be:

```
def index
  @q = School.search(params[:q])
  @products = @q.result.order("school_name ASC").page(params[:page]).per(50)
  ...
```

Further:

On the search form you are putting up a label and a text field.  But you need to actually use a predicate if you want to search by it.  For example, if you want to search for a specific school then on the form you need to change:

```
  <%= f.label :school_name %>
  <%= f.text_field :school_name %>
```

to be:

```
  <%= f.label :school_name_eq %>
  <%= f.text_field :school_name_eq %>
```

There is an extra `_eq` predicate on the end of the field name - this tells Ransack you want to do an exact search for school when it builds the SQL.  Similarly if you wanted any school which contains the text on the form you can use `:school_name_cont` instead.

Comment: Sorry i posted not so good code, was trying various permutations. However, the error persists as we speak. Also please note that this view is not schools/index.html.erb but home/index.html.erb and that why i added the url.

Comment: You are using `<% search_form_for...` - should be `<%= search_form_for`; I missed this originally (`<%=` tag not `<%`)

Comment: So do you originally render the view from a home controller index action?  If so you need to initialise the search object there too with `@q = School.search` without any parameters.

Comment: Maybe you need to update your question with the code as it stands now because the error you are getting means that the first argument to `search_form_for` (`@q` in my example) was not created by `School.search`.

Answer (score 1):

The trick to everything that solved the problem was to simple replace `Model.search()` with `Model.ransack()`.

Answer (score 0):

**# app/controller/**

```
before_filter :set_search

def set_search
  @search=Product.search(params[:q])
end
```

```